# JavaScript Replace on JQuery object appears not to be working

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I'm trying to get the following code working which 'should' scan for {count} and then replace this with the number '1'.

Full Code:

http://jsbin.com/miciqe/7/edit

Snippet:

```
$('#data').html( function() {
    $(this).html().replace('{count}', '1');
  });
```

It seems simple enough, set the html to (a function which gets the html, does a replace, returns that resulting value).

Can't figure out for the life of me what is going wrong.

Could someone point out the 'hopefully' obvious?

**Update**

Thanks to bic,
Working code examples for future reference: [Solution 1](http://jsbin.com/miciqe/8/edit),  [Solution 2](http://jsbin.com/miciqe/12/edit) (Recommended)

*P.s. I changed it to regexp, so that all occurances of {count} would be replaced in the string.*

Comment: I've also tried regexp: replace(/\{count\}/gi, '1'); to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return the string:

```
$('#data').html( function(index, oldHtml) {
    return oldHtml.replace('{count}', '1');
});
```

Using your method, instead of the params that are passed in by default:

```
$('#data').html(function () {
    return $(this).html().replace('{count}', '1');
}
```

[Updated JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ruzuzohadolu/1/edit)

Comment: Thanks for that, strange, I did have the return in there before, and it didnt work, and with all the changing about I missed it out in the jsbin example, but putting it in now works???

Comment: Which is better, and why? using $(this) or using those index,oldHTML parameters. Never used them before myself... quite new..

Comment: Strange Andy, maybe its a jsbin thing?

Comment: @Russell, yeah, looks a bit ropey if you ask me :)

Comment: @Russell I would say that using the passed in params is better. When you use `$(this).html()` you are requiring jQuery to re-retrieve the element, and then pull down the html again as well. The result you get has already been run once, and passed into the method. The is really no reason to not use it.

Comment: Thanks Bic, fantastic work. Approved as answer as well as great detailed explanation of the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Your closure doesn't return any value to be set as html, your code should read:

```
    $('#data').html( function() {
        return $(this).html().replace('{count}', '1');
    });
```

[Working demo](http://jsbin.com/sadizibahipe/)

Answer (score -1):

As you doubted, this is a very small issue. You are replacing the {count} by 1 but not resetting it back. Try the following:

```
$('#data').html( function() {
  $('#data').html($('#data').html().replace('{count}','1'));
});
```

Comment: I thought of this, but my concern was what if there are more than one match of #data (not for ID's, but if you were using classes) then it would get mixed up, no? And the double query being run too.

Comment: This is highly redundant and inefficient. Why use a function callback and then do exactly what you could have done without it?

`$('#data').html($('#data').html().replace('{count}','1'));` acomplishes the same thing without the callback.